# How to code this censoring program for a large vector?

Tags: loops, c++11, vector

If vector banned has many values i am not able to generated a loop to compare vector banned from vector words too see if they are same string

```
 int main()

 {

  vector<string>banned = {"warez","blood"};       //words to be censored
  vector<string>words;

 for(string t;cin >>t;) words.push_back(t);   //creating database
 cout<<'\n';

for(string i : words) cout<<i<<'\t';      //non censored output of 
                                                  database

 cout<<'\n';

 for(int i = 0;i<words.size();++i)            //censored output of database

 if(banned[0] == words[i] || banned[1] == words[i])
    cout<<"Bleep"<<'\t';

 else cout<<words[i]<<'\t';

  }
```

Comment: Could you format your code better?

Comment: maybe using `std::set` instead of `std::vector`? Anyway you could copy the values in `banned` in a `std::set` to make simpler the checks.

Comment: And why exactly can't you do it?

Comment: Lol I am only 4 days into c++ ; So i have to use most basic code to write it also since i am following a book i think i should use the concepts that are taught But feel free to make references to material and thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::find` on the banned list. ref: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

```
#include<algorithm>
...
if(std::find(banned.begin(), banned.end(), words[i]) != banned.end()) 
    std::cout << "Bleep" << '\t';
```

Comment: Can i use a loop inside if loop to check for equality of strings then how to use || (or) operator to my advantage

Comment: You cannot loop inside if, but you can call a function which can do anything and return a `bool`. For your case, `std::find`, does check the equality in a loop like you want, so you don't have to write your own function with loop in it.